# Tablets: android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" and screen disabling issue

Tags: android, rotation, screen-orientation

I have application with screen rotation.
rotating mechanism i handle with `configChanges`:

```
<activity
    android:name=".ui.activity.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
    android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

**Problem:**
When user turn off screen, rotate device on 90 degrees and unblock it screen start with "old" orientation of my app, it look ugly.

here scheme:

[image] after block and rotate i get this 
[image: after screen rotation] blink and app come to normal

try it on Nexus 5(android v5) and Nesus 10(android v4.4), at phones all works fine

Answer (score 2):

Adding `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` tells the system that you are going to handle these config changes yourself, and for the system to not do anything about it.
By removing them, your activity will be recreated with the correct layouts when you rotate.

If you're using `configChanges` to avoid the activity being recreated, I feel bad for you son.

Comment: _tells the system that you are going to handle these config changes yourself, and for the system to not do anything about it._

Yeah, I know that.

My layouts pretty simple and I didn't need activity recreation at all cause of [problem in android core](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=69403).

_I feel bad for you son_
Should not be. Will be better if try you say something informative for this concrete case.

Comment: Linked issue doesn't appear to have anything to do with rotation of the activity, and seems that you can just remove the fragments in reverse order (C1, B1, A1) such that the new fragments are activated in the correct order. Do you mean that there is a problem with your fragments getting restored after the rotation?

Comment: _seems that you can just remove the fragments_ Yes, I can remove fragments after rotation, but it cause bad user experience(imagine: you create some post and after rotation your content is lost) Mechanism for restoring it in normal order pretty hard to realize correctly(without bugs). 
_Do you mean that there is a problem with your fragments getting restored after the rotation?_ Nope, I know how to use _onSaveInstanceState()_ it's not a problem.